# Three phase well pump wire colors

Tags: wire, well-pump

This question is not stemming from any immediate practical application. But I am curious about the color of wire insulation used for three phase 208V or 240V well pumps. Looking online I see a lot of submersible well pump cables that are black/red/yellow/green. But I don't see any that are black/red/blue/green. I know black/red/blue/green colors are somewhat customary (but not mandatory) for 208V. Also white if neutral is used.

1. Is it an electrical code requirement in the US to use wire listed as submersible well pump wire under UL 83 for well pumps? What part of the NEC calls that out? I am talking about the wire that goes down the bore to the pump motor.
2. I know the NEC is silent about colors, but what is the customary color, if any, of insulation used for 3-phase well pump wire and cable (208-240V)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no required NEC color coding for 3 phase pumps or motors with the exception of a high leg or wild leg be on B phase and marked orange, there are industry standards like Brown orange yellow for 480 but they can all be black. The only other requirement the phasing be front to back, top to bottom or right to left when talking about phase numbering in the NEC. I should add the ground is bare or insulated green.

To update for edit:  black red blue is the normal 3 phase color code For most companies but not all.
I do have a concern that you may be confusing 3 phase and 3 wire pumps 2 very different things. If you have an inverter you may have a 3 phase pump but if only standard voltage 240 3 wire is not the same.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my questions. Do you know whether the NEC mandates that well pump wires or cable must be UL 83? Or the customary (not NEC mandated) colors used for well-pumps?

Comment: Maybe my question is bad. I am saying "UL 83".  But I guess that is a broad standard. Maybe I will change it to "submersible well pump wire."

Comment: Ok I said the NEC has no code for the colors that means the colors are not mandated all the pump wires can be black, blue, red or any other color identified as a normal current carrying conductor. The mandated colors in the NEC for ac wiring is green or bare for ground, white or gray for neutral other than a high leg 3 phase being orange there are NO colors mandated. The wire type is a wire listed for a wet location is required. Colors are optional. Mike edit your question you specifically ask about code requirement item 1 and I have answered this 2x

Comment: Question is not about mandated, but customary.

Comment: That is item 2 and it depends one of the large companies I worked for had a different color code than the old recommended colors for 208 3 phase and 480 I could give there version and my current company would say different , it also depends on where the pump was built but many have the winding connections only 1 -3 or thru 9 or 12 depending on the number of poles.

Comment: Cables rated for submersible well pump use do not seem to be available for the most part in any color other than black/red/yellow/green. I know those cables are used for three wire pumps. What cables would be used for three-phase pumps? Would they use the same cable or would they find the seemingly unavailable black/red/blue/green submersible well pump cable?

Comment: Ok because black red yellow green is common for a 3 wire with a controller or box for the start capacitor  not 3 phase. And it matters because start and run may have different sized caps.

Comment: Yes. Definitely. But I don't see individual wires for sale rated for submersible well-pump usage. Also, I do not see cables other than black/red/yellow/green. Also, the leads on three phase pumps seem to be black/red/yellow/green (based on pictures online). So I am wondering if it is common practice to use the black/red/yellow/green cable for three-phase submersible well pump installations.

Comment: As I tried to say in my original answer most 3 phase installs follow the color convention or are all black or whatever color is ordered we don’t buy a hundred or 200’ of each color we buy a spool if rotation is critical as it is on most pumps when we connect we use phase tape so we get rotation correct. Note when you splice separate your splices so if they leak they won’t short out, well water is not highly conductive in most cases but having a inch or 2 difference in height can prevent a short if the splice leaks.

Comment: So you use individual wires, not cables. Where are you finding individual wires rated for submersible well pump usage though. Maybe I just haven't looked in the right place.

Comment: I think the last I got was at wire and cable my way . Com. All 1 word no spaces. I will verify in the am.

Comment: Wire and cable your way. I only find cables that are submersible well-pump regulated. No individual wires. The cables are all black/red/yellow/green. I guess I better move all this chatter to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111741/discussion-between-mkeith-and-ed-beal).